# C# WPF DataSource property not recognizing

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, odp.net

I am trying to build a very simple WPF Application using C# on .Net F/W 4.0. When i click a button, i wanted it to run a sql query(stored in "finalupdatedsql1" variable) against oracle database. **I want the results on a Datagrid**. For some reason Datagrid.DataSource property is not recognized. Could anyone help me with an alternate approach or correct my code? FYI, I am using ODP.Net and Oracle connection tests fine. Thanks.

```
private void RunSQL_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cmd = new OracleCommand(finalupdatedsql1, conn);//finalupdatedsql1 has the sqlquery in string representation.
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
        cb = new OracleCommandBuilder(da);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        MyDataGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];//DataSource not showing up in intellisense or recognizing


        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: `MyDataGrid.DataSource` is for winforms `DatagridView` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.itemssource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

The `DataSource` property would be a `Windows Forms` application.

Comment: ds.Tables[0] gives an error. Changing it to (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ds.Tables[0] resolves it, but is it suggestable?